# How can I connect the notion integration to the specific notion page?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I'm using a free-version notion and created my own integration [in this page](https://www.notion.so/my-integrations).
The integration targets the correct workspace and so, I wanted to connect the integration to the page in the workspace.

[This readme](https://github.com/thomashirtz/notion-scholar#3-share-the-database-with-the-integration)says my integration can be connected to the page from the "invite" button and I clicked the button. However, there wasn't any integration nor "select an invitation" guide like
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBjEd.png).

I wonder some paid plan is needed to connect the integration, but is there any other solutions for this problem???

Answer (score 8):

I think this option just moved to a separate section:

1. Click the three dots in the upper right corner of your Notion Doc (...)
2. Under `Connections` select `Add Connections`
3. Search for the name of your connection

Comment: as of the end of 2022, this should be the accepted answer.